# Assuming one variable is greater than another variable

Tags: assumptions

I want to add the assumption that `M>m`, but I am not sure how to do that.
I tried

```
Assuming[M > m, M > m]
```

But this yields `M>m`, but I expected it to yield `true`.

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Assumptions work correctly, for example in ``Simplify``: ``Simplify[M>m, Assumptions -> M>m]`` yields ``True``. You have to use one of the "magic" functions like ``Simplify, FullSimplify, Refine ...``

Comment: 1. I still do not understand why what I wrote above does not yield `true`. 2. what I am actually trying to solve is a simple quadratic equation where the coefficients are complicated expressions of some other parameters. This calculation is never-ending, and I thought that the proper assumptions might help.

Comment: Assumptions are only used by functions that make use of the option `Assumptions`. `Assuming` has no options so its second argument does not make use of its first argument. To make use of the assumption, use `Assuming[M > m, Simplify[M > m]]`

Comment: so I guess that this means that `Assuming[M>m, Solve[...]]` should work.

Comment: Depends on which Mma version you are using. With later versions, `Solve` takes the option `Assumptions`, with earlier versions it does not. Evaluating `Options[Solve, Assumptions]` will indicate whether it does.

Comment: I tried the following: `Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, 4 ac > b^2}, 
 Solve[a \[Tau]^2 + b \[Tau] + c == 0, \[Tau], Reals]]` and I get this answer: `{{\[Tau] -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-(b/(2 a)) - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c]/(2 a), 
    a < b^2/(4 c) && ac > b^2/4]}, {\[Tau] -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-(b/(2 a)) + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c]/(2 a), 
    a < b^2/(4 c) && ac > b^2/4]}}`. I do not understand why the assumptions do not work. I tried to check with `Options[Solve, Assumptions]`, which gives `{Assumptions :> $Assumptions}`. I have Mathematica 12.2.

Comment: You are missing a space in `ac` and the assumption should be `4 a c < b^2`. The result will be a `ConditionalExpression` unless you simplify it. `Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, 4 a c < b^2}, 
 Solve[a \[Tau]^2 + b \[Tau] + c == 0, \[Tau], Reals] // Simplify]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just not simplifying.

```
Assuming[M > m, Simplify[M > m]]
(*True*)
```